# SVNSERVE access control, authz file

Tags: svnserve

I have followed a tutorial and it works without the authz file, but when I add the file in in svnserve.conf
my root folder: /home/repos/

project 1 svnserve.conf:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write

password-db = /home/reops/passwd-users

authz-db = /home/repos/authz
```

if authz-db is commented out then it works but doesnt if its uncommented.

authz file:

```
[/project1]
nick = rw
harry = r
* =
```

when I checkout I get access denied for nick and harry even though its the right password for each user and they have access in authz file.

the error I get is authorization denied. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

the authz file was not formatted properly, it should have been:

```
[/]

[project2:/]
nick = rw
harry = r
* =
```